# UITableView using NSMutableArray to display dynamic content

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsnotification

Been looking for a solution for a long while now, but still no success, perhaps someone here can help me.

I created an application that runs a thread that communicates with a webserver in the background. Occasionally the thread receives information that I'd like to display in a UITableView. Because of the dynamic nature of the content I decided a NSMutableArray should be sufficient to store the information from the webserver.

Whenever I receive information from the webservice my AppDelegate sends a notification. My UITableView registers to receive certain kinds of information which I intend to show in the UITableView.

The initWithStyle method of the UITableViewController contains the following code:

```
- (void)addContact:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"%@", [note object]);

    NSString *message = (NSString *)[note object];
    NSString *name = [[message componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:2];

    contact = name;
    [array addObject:contact];
}   

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test1", @"test2", nil];

    tv.dataSource = self;
    tv.delegate = self;

    self.tableView = tv;
}
```

The array in AddContact contains the data displayed in the TableView. All data I manually add to the array in ViewDidLoad: will be shown in the table, but it doesn't happen for the data added in the AddContact: method.

Anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the update happening on the main thread?
You can use this sort of refresh function to make sure it does.

```
- (void)refresh {
if([NSThread isMainThread])
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
}
else 
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

}